# A class derived Control that has a Canvas in template, I want to work like canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, canvas, controls

I have a class `Tableau` derived from `Windows.Controls.Control`, its template contains a `Canvas`:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Tableau}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Tableau}">
                    <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer"
                                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" 
                                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                      >
                            <Canvas x:Name="Diagram" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=Background}"
                                    >
                                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                    <ScaleTransform CenterX="0"
                                                    CenterY="0"
                                                    ScaleX="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=Scale}"
                                                    ScaleY="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=Scale}"
                                                    />
                                </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                            </Canvas>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

and `Tableau` class is:

```
    public class Tableau:Control
    {
        private Canvas _canvas;
        public Canvas Canvas
        {
            get { return _canvas; }
        }

        static Tableau()
        {
            FrameworkElement.DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
                typeof(Tableau), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Tableau)));
        }

        public Tableau()
            : base()
        {
            this.Loaded += Tableau_Loaded;
        }

        private void Tableau_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _canvas = (Canvas)this.Template.FindName("Diagram", this);
        }
    }
```

I want to use this as a canvas, something like this:

```
    <local:Tableau>
            <Rectangle Fill="AliceBlue" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Top="10"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="AliceBlue" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Left="130" Canvas.Top="50"/>
    </local:Tableau>
```

It is possible or not, if yes how?

Comment: You may derive from ItemsControl, and set the ItemsPanel property by a Style.

Comment: In case you already saw my answer, I just did a bit more testing and updated it. It should be a more complete solution now.

Answer (score -1):

You could define a property `Children`, have it return the `Children` collection from the internal `Canvas`, and apply the [`ContentProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.contentpropertyattribute) attribute. Here's a modified version of the class I tested:

```
[ContentProperty(nameof(Children))]
public class Tableau : Control
{
    static Tableau()
    {
        FrameworkElement.DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(Tableau), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Tableau)));
    }

    public Tableau() : base()
    {
        UpdateDefaultStyle();
    }

    private Canvas canvas;
    public Canvas Canvas
    {
        get
        {
            if (canvas == null) { ApplyTemplate(); }
            return canvas;
        }
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        canvas = (Canvas)GetTemplateChild("Diagram");
    }

    public UIElementCollection Children
    {
        get { return Canvas.Children; }
    }
}
```

Note that I use `OnApplyTemplate` instead of `Loaded`, so that I can get the internal `Canvas` (and thus the `Children` collection) even before the `Tableau` loads. I also use `UpdateDefaultStyle` in the constructor to ensure the default template is available to load as early as possible.

Comment: Thanks but its not work. this "public UIElementCollection Children { get { return Canvas.Children; }" has error. I changed Canvas.Children to canvas.Children but not work.

Comment: @Davoud Wow, I have no clue how I thought it was working before. Well, third time's the charm. I made another change and tested it again. Tell me if it works for you now.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. but not work like Canvas.
When I use something like this
<code>
        <local:Tableau HorizontalRulerVisibility="Visible"
  ...
            >
            **<local:Tableau.Children>
                <Rectangle Width="81" Height="67" Fill="Aqua" Margin="100"/>
            </local:Tableau.Children>**
        </local:Tableau>
</code>
at design time everything OK except that for move item must use margin not Canvas.SetLeft and top.
at runtime I have this error: _{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}_ at **get { return Canvas.Children; }**